# How do I use visibility widget on drop down

Tags: flutter, dart

I want visibility  of other drop downs only when "yes" is selected other wise it should remain invisible

Here is the code:

```html
    bool condition false;
 
                             Visibility(
                            child: DropDownWidget(
                          list: ["Yes","No"],
                          data: patientConsent,
                          hint: getTranslated(context,"select_dropdown"),
                          heading: getTranslated(context,"patient_consent"),
                          onChange: (val){
                            setState(() {

                            });
                          },
                          ),
                          ),
                          
                             Visibility(
                            visible: condition,
                            child: Column(
                          children:[
                          CustomFromField(
                          heading: getTranslated(context, "sample_id"),
                          controller: idno,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First intialize condition as global, value with false. Then change the value based on the value selected in drop down.

```
bool condition = false;


     onChange: (val){                  
            if(val == "Yes"){
               setState(() {
               condition = true;
              });
           }else{
              setState(() {
              condition = false;
            });
```